# LinkedIn share to individual

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

How do I share to an individual on LinkedIn, i.e., send a message to someone on LinkedIn?

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/tags-and-templates#share

The above link doesn't specify how to pass the LinkedIn id of the user.

Comment: Did you got some way to do this? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: NO I dindt if you find....let me know

Answer (score 1):

The consensus appears to be: There is no way to setup a URL on LinkedIn to share to a particular individual.

*If a user wants, they can select to send their message to everyone or to a particular person, but it is up to the user:*

[image]

Look at the documentation URL you have: this question is so old, that the documentation now 404's and redirects to a blank page.  Here's the new documentation: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Link API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

In fact, in 2013, you could use other parameters besides `url`, like `summary` and `title`.  Since being acquired by Microsoft, LinkedIn Share API is now *strictly limited to only the `url` parameter.*

Seeing as they have been stripping other parameters from the API, I think it is unlikely that they will be adding new ones soon, even a to-user parameter.