# Telegram URI Scheme to Send Message to Specified User

Tags: http, telegram

I'm looking for a way to send message to telegram user from website with specific message. Something like WhatsApp's

```
https://wa.me/12345678901?text=Custom+message
```

I've found just this:

```
https://t.me/username
```

This allows to start chat with custom user but with blank message field.

Is there any way to start a chat with custom user (even he is not in my phonebook or userlist) with fulfilled message field?

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following formats should work:

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
tg://msg_url?url={url}&text={text}
```

This means you will have as options:

- `url` : URL to share.
- `text` : Text to share.

**[The official documentation confirms as much.](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons)**

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Such url will open telegram and ask to select a user. I need something that will open direct chat with custom user.

Comment: Hi, Ariakas!  Right, as indicated by the documentation, there is no such thing.  Feel free to take a look at this related answer I have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840557/2430549

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="tg://msg?text=Hello&to=+42333" id="telegram_share" class="mobileShare" title="inviteFriends" alt="telegram_share”/>
```

You can try redirecting above link in WebView.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That link just opens telegram without opened chat. I've tried phone numbers with/without plus sign and username.